# Making bootstrap modal work in a framework7 web app

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-framework-7

I am having trouble with including bootstrap modal onto a framework7 app.

I suspect that framework7 is suppressing boostrap modal from appearing.

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgb0n3cq/2/).

```
    <div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="left sliding"><a href="" class="back link"><i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Back</span></a></div>
    <div class="">
      <span id="project_name" class="center sliding">Title</span>
    </div>
      <div class="right">
        <a id="create_task" style="">Create</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pages navbar-through ">
  <div data-page="about" class="page no-toolbar page-on-center">
    <div class="page-content">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>


      <div class="content-block">
        <p>This project is made possible because of these open-source projects & beta testers.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="content-block-title">Open Source</div>
      <div class="content-block">
        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <a href="http://framework7.io">Framework7</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <a href="https://vuejs.org">Vuejs</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <a href="http://rubyonrails.org">Ruby on Rails</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <a href="http://fontawesome.io">Font Awesome</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <a href="https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios">Axios</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <a href="https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari">Kaminari</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <a href="https://github.com/puma/puma">Puma</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content-block-title">Thanks to these beta testers</div>
      <div class="content-block">
        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <li>John Doe</li>
          <li>Nathan</li>
          <li>Sharon days</li>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content-block-title">Logo</div>
      <div class="content-block">
        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <b>Lau Jun Wen</b>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone give me some pointers on what is wrong? There is no error message. Appreciate any feedback/advice to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made several changes to correct the problems:

1. Removed the `modal.min.js`.  This was the problem causing the modal to open and close again.
2. Re-ordered the bootstrap/framework7 CSS + JS to put framework7 after the bootstrap (so that the framework7 overrides bootstrap when necessary).
3. Put the `myModal` div at the end of the code so that its z-index does not get blocked by a parent `div`'s less-high z-index.
4. Add some custom CSS to make the modal show up correctly.  This is necessary due to using two frameworks.

Here is the final code:

```css
#myModal.modal {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale(1);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/1.6.4/js/framework7.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/1.6.4/css/framework7.ios.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="left sliding"><a href="" class="back link"><i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Back</span></a></div>
    <div class="">
      <span id="project_name" class="center sliding">Title</span>
    </div>
      <div class="right">
        <a id="create_task" style="">Create</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pages navbar-through ">
  <div data-page="about" class="page no-toolbar page-on-center">
    <div class="page-content">
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>


      <div class="content-block">
        <p>This project is made possible because of these open-source projects & beta testers.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="content-block-title">Open Source</div>
      <div class="content-block">
        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <a href="http://framework7.io">Framework7</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <a href="https://vuejs.org">Vuejs</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <a href="http://rubyonrails.org">Ruby on Rails</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <a href="http://fontawesome.io">Font Awesome</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <a href="https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios">Axios</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <a href="https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari">Kaminari</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <a href="https://github.com/puma/puma">Puma</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content-block-title">Thanks to these beta testers</div>
      <div class="content-block">
        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <li>John Doe</li>
          <li>Nathan</li>
          <li>Sharon days</li>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content-block-title">Logo</div>
      <div class="content-block">
        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <b>Lau Jun Wen</b>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qgb0n3cq/4/)